# c++ What process is listening on a certain port in windows

Tags: c++, windows, visual-c++, networking

I have created a program in visual c++, where i have implemented a web service. 
The web service is set to listen on port 80, but if another program already is using this port, the web service fail to start up.

So when the webservice can't start, I would like to have a function or method, which can get the name of the process, that currently uses port 80. Then i can print an error to the user, and ask him to close the process.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[GetExtendedTcpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365928.aspx) and [GetExtendedUdpTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365930.aspx) give you a list of network connections. You can walk through this list and check if a program is using port 80 (it provides process IDs as well).

Comment: Thanks. the GetExtendedTcpTable function is a little difficult to use, because there should be some bugs in the implementation from Microsoft, but with help from this site, i got it working: http://www.mychinaworks.com/blog/lshen/2008/04/16/220/

Answer (score 1):

I have a solution using Qt in C++:

```
/**
 * \brief Find id of the process that is listening to given port.
 * \param port A port number to which a process is listening.
 * \return The found process id, or 0 if not found.
 */
uint findProcessListeningToPort(uint port)
{
   QString netstatOutput;
   {
      QProcess process;
      process.start("netstat -ano -p tcp");
      process.waitForFinished();
      netstatOutput = process.readAllStandardOutput();
   }
   QRegularExpression processFinder;
   {
      const auto pattern = QStringLiteral(R"(TCP[^:]+:%1.+LISTENING\s+(\d+))").arg(port);
      processFinder.setPattern(pattern);
   }
   const auto processInfo = processFinder.match(netstatOutput);
   if (processInfo.hasMatch())
   {
      const auto processId = processInfo.captured(1).toUInt();
      return processId;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would consider, as a first attempt, running `netstat` as an external process and capturing/parsing the output. It gives you the active connections.

Comment: It tested this method and the "netstat -noa" would also do the job, but I would need to pipe the output to a file and then parse it in my program. The GetExtendedTcpTable gives me an array in c++ with all the information.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if there is a way to do this via an API (not a windows programmer), however you could try netstat -abo as a shell command, then look for TCP and port 80 in the resulting string, and you'll have the binary name...

EDIT: I believe you need XP SP2 atleast for this to work...