# Identify process is running in certain port C/C++ Windows

Tags: c++, c, windows, networking, network-programming

Can anyone tell me how to identify which process is running in certain port in Windows using C/C++. I want to write a simple port scanner. When I find some ports are opened, I also want to print which process is running in each port.
Thanks.

Comment: I honestly hope that this is impossible.

Comment: Why is it impossible?

Comment: it could be a lots of security issues if getting process is possible

Comment: it must be possible because you can see it with `netstat -anbo` command.

Comment: The main question is whether you want to scan local or remote ports, and therefore whether you want local or remote processes.

Comment: I want to scan local only. Do you have any idea to do that?

Comment: And the other question is, given that netstat already exists, why do you need to do this at all?

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ What process is listening on a certain port in windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4041003/c-what-process-is-listening-on-a-certain-port-in-windows)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

void executeCMD(const char *cmd, char *result)
{
    char buf_ps[1024];
    char ps[1024]={0};
    FILE *ptr;
    strcpy(ps, cmd);
    if((ptr=popen(ps, "r"))!=NULL)
    {
        while(fgets(buf_ps, 1024, ptr)!=NULL)
        {
            strcat(result, buf_ps);
            if(strlen(result)>1024)
                break;
        }
        pclose(ptr);
        ptr = NULL;
    }
    else
    {
        printf("popen %s error\n", ps);
    }
}

int main()
{
    char result[1024];
    executeCMD( "netstat -ano", result);
    printf("%s", result );
    return 0;
}
```

maybe, you could have a try!

Comment: This is a really crummy way of doing it.  Calling an external process, ok it's a lot simpler than using the API.  But the buffer handling is atrocious.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution using Qt in C++:

```
/**
 * \brief Find all ids of processes that is listening to any port.
 * \return A key-value map that keys are ports and values are corresponding process id.
 */
QMap<uint, uint> findAllProcessesListeningToAnyPort()
{
   QMap<uint, uint> portToProcessId;
   QString netstatOutput;
   {
      QProcess process;
      process.start("netstat -ano -p tcp");
      process.waitForFinished();
      netstatOutput = process.readAllStandardOutput();
   }
   QRegularExpression processFinder;
   {
      const auto pattern = R"(TCP[^:]+:(?<port>\d+).+LISTENING\s+(?<pid>\d+))";
      processFinder.setPattern(pattern);
   }
   auto processInfoItr = processFinder.globalMatch(netstatOutput);
   while (processInfoItr.hasNext())
   {
      const auto processInfo = processInfoItr.next();
      const auto port = processInfo.captured("port").toUInt();
      const auto processId = processInfo.captured("pid").toUInt();
      portToProcessId.insert(port, processId);
   }
   return portToProcessId; 
}
```